# sql server connection error using jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I tried below code and I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://Usatlbyq.na.ko.com:1433;integratedSecurity=true;
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at testing.testingsql.main(testingsql.java:19)
```

I am using below code:

```
package testing;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class testingsql {
    public static Connection conn = null;
    //private String dbName = null;


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Usatlbyq.na.ko.com:1433;integratedSecurity=true;");//here put the new simple url.
            System.out.println("succesful connection");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public ResultSet runSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        return sta.executeQuery(sql);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your mssql version?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL should be `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname`

Comment: The used URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://Usatlbyq.na.ko.com:1433;integratedSecurity=true;` looks OK to me. The `DatabaseName` parameter is not required.